# Why is this code not storing any data in the database?

Tags: prolog

I have this code and I'm trying to calculate the grade for the students but when I try to add students in the database using the add_students nothing gets added.

I tried checking the entries in the database but it remains empty. I'm new to prolog so I'm not sure whats causing this problem

```
`:- dynamic letter_grade/2, final_grade/2, student_grades/7.

% Add student data to the database.
add_students([]).
add_students([[Name, HW1, HW2, HW3, Midterm, FinalExam, Project] | Rest]) :-
  asserta(student_grades(Name, HW1, HW2, HW3, Midterm, FinalExam, Project)),
  add_students(Rest).

% Calculate the final grade for a student using specified weights and store it in the database.
calculate_final_grade(Name, FinalGrade) :-
  student_grades(Name, HW1, HW2, HW3, Midterm, FinalExam, Project),
  HwWeight is 0.20, % Weight for Homeworks (20%)
  ExamWeight is 0.40, % Weight for Exams (40%)
  ProjectWeight is 0.40, % Weight for the Project (40%)
  % Calculate the final grade on a 100-point scale.
  UnscaledFinalGrade is (HwWeight * (HW1 + HW2 + HW3) + ExamWeight * (Midterm + FinalExam) + ProjectWeight * Project),
  FinalGrade is UnscaledFinalGrade * 100,
  asserta(final_grade(Name, FinalGrade)).

% Calculate the letter grade based on the final grade and store it in the database.
calculate_letter_grade(Name, LetterGrade) :-
  final_grade(Name, FinalGrade),
  (FinalGrade >= 90 -> LetterGrade = "A";
   FinalGrade >= 85 -> LetterGrade = "A-";
   FinalGrade >= 80 -> LetterGrade = "B+";
   FinalGrade >= 75 -> LetterGrade = "B";
   FinalGrade >= 70 -> LetterGrade = "B-";
   FinalGrade >= 65 -> LetterGrade = "C+";
   FinalGrade >= 60 -> LetterGrade = "C";
   LetterGrade = "F"),
  asserta(letter_grade(Name, LetterGrade)).
% Example usage.
add_multiple_students_and_calculate_grades :-
  Students = [
    ["John Doe", 95, 88, 78, 85, 92, 89],
    ["Alice Smith", 87, 91, 79, 93, 88, 90],
    ["Bob Johnson", 76, 82, 85, 78, 80, 85]
  ],
  add_students(Students),
  forall(member([Name | _], Students), calculate_final_grade(Name, _)),
  forall(member([Name | _], Students), calculate_letter_grade(Name, _))`.
```

Comment: Show how you load and run your code. Copy-paste what you type in the terminal and what comes back at you.

Comment: When I run this in a single query I'm getting desired Output but when I run each query one after another I get False as a output from the second and third query. ->  add_multiple_students_and_calculate_grades,
calculate_letter_grade("Bob Johnson", LetterGrade),
students_with_letter_grade("B+", Student_List).

Comment: OK I am not going to decipher this. Provide a reproducible example in your question and your chance of getting a good answer will be higher.

Comment: Usual reminder: You can step through your program, to see exactly what is happening and where it is going wrong, using e.g. [trace](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=debugger).